# onDestroy() gets called when I am trying to call startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I've noticed a bizarre behavior in my app.

I have a `StartActivity` which checks whether the user is authenticated (this is necessary to view the content). If yes, it calls `finish()` and starts (`startActivity`) `Activity` with a content.

If the user is not authenticated the `SignInActivity` is started by `startActivityForResult`.

This is when strange things start to happen - **immediately** after calling `startActivityForResult`, `onDestoryed` is called. When I cancel my `SignInActivity`, `onCreate` is called once again in `StartActivity`, and `SignInActivity` is started. When I cancel the `Activity` once again `StartActivity` calls `finish()` (which is expected)

**Edit**

@Seshu Vinay has asked what does 'cancel `SignInActivity`' mean.

It basically means responding to software/hardware `back` press (not in Action Bar !) and depending on default result.

**Edist #2**
Heres my `Manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignIn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        />
        <activity
            android:name=".ContentActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT #3**
Way I start `SignIn` in `onCreate`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 123);
```

I've created a trivial project which recreates a problem availible [here](https://github.com/bujal0/activityqueue) (github)

Comment: Try to change your Manifest file to handle screen orientation, screen size and keyboard hidden

Comment: So, clicking on cancel button, it should by default come to onActivityResult() with resultCode 0(RESULT_CANCELED). Could you get that?

Comment: Post your manifest please.

Comment: @SeshuVinay the actual steps are StartActivity(SA)`onCreate`{ `startActivityForResult` } SA`onDestroy`, SignInActivity`backPressed`, SA`onCreate`{`startActivityForResult`}, SA`onActivityResult` with result 0.

Comment: result 0 is expected. But onDestroy and onCreate shouldn't be called. Please post the Intent that you used in startActivityForResult(). Does it have any flags?

Comment: I know that 0 is expected, when signed-in `RESULT_OK` is set. I've edited my post yet again.

Comment: Do you have the debug option "finish activities" set? This could cause the behaviour you are describing.